# How can I guess action name and module name from URL in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, routes

For example, I have a referer URL. I want to redirect to a page according to the previous page's module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a code snippet on [this page](http://snippets.symfony-project.org/snippet/61). To get module and action of the previous page, you will use the referer:

```
    $referer = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getReferer();
    // you have to check if the referer is not empty and is a page of your site
    ....
    // then get the module and action:
    $url = parse_url($referer);
    $path = trim($url['path'], '/');
    if (!sfConfig::get('sf_no_script_name') && $pos = strpos($path, '/') )
    {
        $path = substr($path, $pos+1);
    }
    $params = sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->findRoute('/'.$path);
    $module = $params['parameters']['module'];
    $action = $params['parameters']['action'];
```